# Sorting and formatting dates angular

Tags: angularjs

I have some data which I am displaying using angular and datatables. Now I want this data to be sorted by date. My code looks like this.

```
<table dataTable="ng"
       class="table table-striped table-bordered hover"
       dt-options="dtOptions">
    <thead>
    <tr >
        <th>Date/Time</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
      ...
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items | orderBy : 'timestamp' : true">
        <td>{{x.timestamp | date: 'medium'}}</td>
        <td>{{x.user.firstname}} {{x.user.lastname}}</td>
    ...
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However it seems I can only format the date OR sort it but not both together. If I remove the format it sorts, otherwise it won't.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is working with no problem (Run the snippet ...).

Is this what you wanted to do ?

Note, that I removed the table directives and replaced this with ng-controller, maybe this is causing you problem ?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('myTable', MyTable)

function MyTable($scope){
    $scope.items = [
      {
        timestamp : 1442188000000,
        user: {
          firstname : 'George'
        }  
      },
      
      {
        timestamp : 1442189022149,
        user: {
          firstname : 'John'
        }  
      },
      {
        timestamp : 1442199022149,
        user: {
          firstname : 'David'
        }  
      }
    ]  
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr >
        <th>Date/Time</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items | orderBy : 'timestamp' : true">
        <td>{{x.timestamp | date: 'medium'}}</td>
        <td>{{x.user.firstname}} {{x.user.lastname}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems the issue is with the format of my timestamp. Its a Date type. Its serialized from a c# DatetimeOffset. Maybe this is the problem, as it will not sort  correctly.

Comment: The timestamp is formatted like this :            timestamp: "2015-09-11T00:00:00+10:00"